# How to extract integer values from strings in ListBoxes in calculations?

Tags: vb.net

I have the code below with two `ListBox` controls and I've added the strings that specify the integers (amounts) so I want to add the integers from the two different `ListBox` controls but the strings also appear in Labels.

How do I reject these strings?

```
Dim intWashandGo, intWashandDry, intWashDryandTyres, intWashDryandPolish As Integer
intWashandGo = 35
intWashandDry = 60
intWashDryandTyres = 70
intWashDryandPolish = 150
Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add("Wash and Go".ToString() & Format(intWashandGo, "currency"))
Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add("Wash and Dry".ToString() & Format(intWashandDry, "currency"))
Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add("Wash, Dry and Tyres".ToString() & Format(intWashDryandTyres, "currency"))
Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add("Wash, Dry, Tyres and Polish".ToString() & Format(intWashDryandPolish, "currency"))

Dim intNoWork, intVacuum, intValet As Integer
intNoWork = 0
intVacuum = 20
intValet = 200

Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Add("No Work".ToString() & Format(intNoWork, "currency"))
Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Add("Vacuum".ToString() & Format(intVacuum, "currency"))
Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Add("Valet".ToString() & Format(intValet, "currency"))

Private Sub CalcButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalcButton.Click
    ExteriorLabel.Text = Format(ExteriorListBox.SelectedItem(), "currency")
    InteriorLabel.Text = Format(InteriorListBox.SelectedItem(), "currency")
    Me.TotalLabel.Text = Format(ExteriorLabel.Text + InteriorLabel.Text, "currency")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the listbox.SelectedValue:

```
Dim intWashandGo, intWashandDry, intWashDryandTyres, intWashDryandPolish As Integer

    intWashandGo = 35
    intWashandDry = 60
    intWashDryandTyres = 70
    intWashDryandPolish = 150

    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intWashandGo, "currency"))
    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items(Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Count -     1).Selectedvalue = intWashandGo

    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intWashandDry, "currency"))
    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items(Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Count -    1).Selectedvalue = intWashandDry 

    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intWashDryandTyres, "currency"))
    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items(Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Count - 1).Selectedvalue = intWashDryandTyres 

    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intWashDryandPolish, "currency"))
    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items(Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Count - 1).Selectedvalue = intWashDryandPolish 


    Debug.WriteLine(Me.ExteriorListBox.SelectedValue)

    Dim intNoWork, intVacuum, intValet As Integer
    intNoWork = 0
    intVacuum = 20
    intValet = 200

    Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intNoWork, "currency"))
    Me.InteriorListBox.Items(Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Count - 1).SelectedValue = intNoWork 

    Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intVacuum, "currency"))
    Me.InteriorListBox.Items(Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Count - 1).SelectedValue = intVacuum 

    Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intValet, "currency"))
    Me.InteriorListBox.Items(Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Count - 1).SelectedValue = intValet 

    Debug.WriteLine(Me.InteriorListBox.SelectedValue)


End Sub

Private Sub CalcButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalcButton.Click

    Dim intTotal As Integer
    Dim intExterior As Integer
    Dim intInterior As Integer
    intExterior = val(Me.ExteriorListBox.SelectedValue)
    intInterior = val(Me.InteriorListBox.SelectedItem)
    intTotal = intExterior + intInterior
    Me.ExteriorLabel.Text = Format(intExterior, "currency")
    Me.InteriorLabel.Text = Format(intInterior, "currency")

    Me.TotalLabel.Text = ("Your total work is".ToString & Format(intTotal, "currency"))
    Me.ClearButton.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearButton.Click
    Me.ExteriorLabel.Text = ""
    Me.InteriorLabel.Text = ""
    Me.TotalLabel.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Afternoon Mr Chartier I've tried the code but it gives me an error...here's my complete code without strings

Comment: Opps ... my bad, the line `Me.TotalLabel.Text = Format(val(ExteriorLabel.Text) + val(InteriorLabel.Text), "currency")` will fail because the text contains a $ sign, use this instead, 'Me.TotalLabel.Text = val(ExteriorListBox.SelectedValue) + val(InteriorListBox.SelectedValue)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim intWashandGo, intWashandDry, intWashDryandTyres, intWashDryandPolish As Integer
    intWashandGo = 35
    intWashandDry = 60
    intWashDryandTyres = 70
    intWashDryandPolish = 150
    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intWashandGo, "currency"))
    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intWashandDry, "currency"))
    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intWashDryandTyres, "currency"))
    Me.ExteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intWashDryandPolish, "currency"))
    Debug.WriteLine(Me.ExteriorListBox.SelectedItem)

    Dim intNoWork, intVacuum, intValet As Integer
    intNoWork = 0
    intVacuum = 20
    intValet = 200

    Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intNoWork, "currency"))

    Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intVacuum, "currency"))

    Me.InteriorListBox.Items.Add(Format(intValet, "currency"))

    Debug.WriteLine(Me.InteriorListBox.SelectedItem)

End Sub

Private Sub CalcButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalcButton.Click
    Dim intTotal As Integer
    Dim intExterior As Integer
    Dim intInterior As Integer
    intExterior = Me.ExteriorListBox.SelectedItem()
    intInterior = Me.InteriorListBox.SelectedItem()
    intTotal = intExterior + intInterior
    Me.ExteriorLabel.Text = Format(intExterior, "currency")
    Me.InteriorLabel.Text = Format(intInterior, "currency")

    Me.TotalLabel.Text = ("Your total work is".ToString & Format(intTotal, "currency"))
    Me.ClearButton.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearButton.Click
    Me.ExteriorLabel.Text = ""
    Me.InteriorLabel.Text = ""
    Me.TotalLabel.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You need to use `.SelectedValue`, `SelectedItem` won't work.

Comment: it gives me this error: System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Value' on type 'String' not found.'